# Ajax - Proteger WebServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, segurança

Estou construindo uma aplicação asp.net MVC e faço muitas chamadas à actions e webservices via ajax (jquery ou angularjs). Como poderia esconder essas chamadas, ou garantir que sejam feitas apenas pela minha aplicação?

Por exemplo:

```
    $('#btnNext').click(function () {    
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Next",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData}),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == "Success") {
                    alert("Done");
                } else {
                    alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An error has occured!!!");
            }
        });
    });
```

Dessa forma meu código esta muito exposto. Qualquer pessoa que acessar o fonte poderá chamar minhas actions e webservices sem minha permissão e obter dados do meu negocio além de carregar o servidor fazendo inúmeras requisições.

Comment: No HomeController você não tem como saber se o usuário está logado? Se estiver, o ActionResult Next retorna, caso contrário, não.

Comment: Não tenho como saber se o usuário esta logado pois seria em uma área aberta do sistema

Answer (score 2):

Implementando o seguinte atributo:

```
public class PermitirCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Repare que isso permite que a origem da requisição seja qualquer uma, porque usei `"*"`.

Para permitir apenas pelo seu site, troque `"*"` pelo endereço do seu site.

Decore a *Action*:

```
[PermitirCrossSiteJson]
public ActionResult Next()
{
    return Json("Sou um JSON protegido", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Dá pra usar no *Controller* também:

```
[PermitirCrossSiteJson]
public class HomeController : Controller
{ ... }
```

### Suporte ao IE9 ou inferior?

[Instale este pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CorsProxy.AspNet/).